# How can I keep an html link from breaking at the end of a line in outlook?

Tags: hyperlink, outlook, html-email

In an HTML email is there a solution to have a link stay together.

For example:

```
This is a story about whatever I want it to be about. Read
More
```

Where 'Read More' is the link. So if it doesn't fit on the line the entire "Read More" would drop instead of just the word "More" but if it does fit on the line none of it drops.

I tried adding `style="display:inline-block"` but it doesn't work in Outlook which is essential. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`?

Comment: hmm didnt really think of that. I just got home though, I'll give it a shot on Monday and if that works will gladly accept. And feel silly!

Comment: Pretty much the answer for Outlook is always something silly.